# Php Session Variables Not Saving

Tags: php, session, session-variables

I am trying to create a log in system for my website, using 1and1 server.

However, the sessions variables did not keep when I moved to a different page.

I thought my code could be the problem, so I create a very simple 2 file site to test.

Here is set.php

```
<?php
session_start();

$_Session['name'] = "alex";
?>
```

And here is view.php

```
<?php
session_start();

echo "hello";
echo $_Session['name'];
?>
```

This was taken from a tutorial on Youtube

The result when i first navigate to the set page, and the to the view page, is just the word 'hello' from my first echo.

Thanks,
A

Comment: `$_SESSION` not `$_Session

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`$_Session` must be set in uppercase, its a [**superglobal**](http://php.net/manual/en/language.variables.superglobals.php).

Change them all to `$_SESSION`

---

As per [**the manual**](http://php.net/manual/en/language.variables.superglobals.php):

> Several predefined variables in PHP are "superglobals", which means they are available in all scopes throughout a script. There is no need to do global $variable; to access them within functions or methods.
>
> These superglobal variables are:
>
> - $GLOBALS
> - $_SERVER
> - $_GET
> - $_POST
> - $_FILES
> - $_COOKIE
> - $_SESSION
> - $_REQUEST
> - $_ENV

---

In regards to the login system you wish to create; if you're not aware of safe methods to use, consider the following:

**Passwords:** - Sidenote: Do not store passwords in plain text.

- Use [**CRYPT_BLOWFISH**](https://security.stackexchange.com/q/36471) or PHP 5.5's [`password_hash()`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.password-hash.php) function. For PHP < 5.5 use the [`password_hash() compatibility pack`](https://github.com/ircmaxell/password_compat).

**Database:**

- Use  [**`mysqli_` with prepared statements**](http://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php), or [**PDO with prepared statements**](http://php.net/pdo.prepared-statements).
- Always use prepared statements.

Comment: Yep. It's *that* easy.

Comment: @JohnConde Pretty much ;) grazie (I didn't see your comment on top when I submitted this)

Comment: That is exactly right, I even remember reading this somewhere else. Need to pay more mind to my code. Thanks a lot.

Comment: @Waq Reload my answer, I have added additional information in regards to your project, in order to use safe methods that could prove useful.

Comment: Thanks a lot, all useful information. I was waiting the 10 minutes to be able to click the tick next to the answer but then went away for a bit!

Comment: @Waq You're very much welcome, glad to have helped!